# HTML in new tab

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

Can someone explain to me how can I open a new tab from a firefox extension, that contains HTML content from a string I have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[gBrowser.addTab](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/tabbrowser#m-addTab), either using a `data:` URL, or opening and empty page then writing to its document. [Info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/tabs#m-appendItem

Answer (score -1):

I do not think this is possible:

1. Whether or not a page or tab opens is based on the user's preferences. If the user has tabbed browsing disabled, the new content will be in a new window and not a tab.
2. Each Browser tab requires a URL. So you would have to make a page, pass it the string as a query string or HTTP POST and then have that page return your string.

The other option is to use something like [this](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/).

Comment: The question said **extension**; that goes a very long way towards avoiding being tied to user preferences for how links in web pages open.